# " __conform__() is not a valid Streamlit command."

Tags: sqlite, pycharm, streamlit

While I was running my code in pycharm, it is showing:

> `__conform__()` is not a valid Streamlit command."

I am trying to store input and result in my streamlit app in sqlite3 database and and display it in tabular format in same streamlit app.

Main code page:`home_task.py`:

```py
import streamlit as st
from homework_db import create_table, add_data


def main():
    st.title("Streamlit Exercise")
    menu = ['Insert', 'Read']
    choice = st.sidebar.selectbox("Menu", menu)
    create_table()
    if choice == 'Insert':
        st.subheader('Lets check Sentiment')
        line = st.text_area("Enter the sentence")
        result = st.text("Positive")
        if st.button("Add Task"):
            add_data(line, result)
            st.success("Successfully added data in database")
    elif choice == 'Read':
        st.subheader('Datatable')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The other file: `homework_db.py`:

```py
import sqlite3
    
conn = sqlite3.connect("homework2_db", check_same_thread=False)
c = conn.cursor()


## database-table-field-datatype##

def create_table():
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS database(sentence TEXT, sentiment TEXT)')


def add_data(line, result):
    c.execute('INSERT INTO database(sentence,sentiment) VALUES(?,?)', (line, result))
    conn.commit()
```

Everything seems fine, I have followed many youtube videos for sql query, it seems right but I am not sure why streamlit is not accepting the code.

I also checked python docs, (https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sqlite3.html#letting-your-object-adapt-itself) but could not figure out how this is related to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `result` is not a string but a Streamlit object:

```py
>>> import streamlit
>>> result = st.text("Positive")
>>> type(result)
<class 'streamlit.delta_generator.DeltaGenerator'>
```

What you need is to do is remove the `st.text()`:

```py
    if choice == 'Insert':
        st.subheader('Lets check Sentiment')
        line = st.text_area("Enter the sentence")
        result = "Positive"  # no st.text()
        if st.button("Add Task"):
            add_data(line, result)
            st.success("Successfully added data in database")
```